How do I avoid storing NuGet packages into source control with pre-SDK style VStudio projects?
In my Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC project based on .NET Framework 4.7.2, I see a Packages folder committed to source control.
I thought I could delete it and use NuGet Restore packages to avoid storing that big amount of files in source control but it was not like that. I get the following error during NuGet Restore:

The missing file is
..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.targets.

Is it possible to avoid storing NuGet packages in source control for .NET Framework Visual Studio projects?

Should you, though? https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/29/nuget-package-restore-considered-harmful

That article is very old: Wednesday, 29 January 2014

So is .NET 4.7.2: 30 April 2018.

If you are using Git, you can use .gitignore file to ignore Nuget Packages.If you are using TFS, you can add disableSourceControlIntegration  in  NuGet.Config file  skip everything in the packages folder.

It looks like your projects that use packages.config, the package appears in the project's packages folder. If you want to  avoid storing nuget packages into source control, you can check  the following:
1.Omitting packages with Git
If you are using Git, you can use the  .gitignore file to ignore NuGet packages (.nupkg) the packages folder when committing your codes.
Example(.gitignore file)
# Ignore NuGet Packages
*.nupkg

# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/[Pp]ackages/*


Omitting packages with Team Foundation Version Control

If you are using TFVC, you can use disableSourceControlIntegration setting in NuGet.Config file.
<solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
</solution>

For more information, please read doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control
By the way for projects that use <PackageReference>, the package is present in the local global-packages folder. You can also use it instead of packages.config.
Hope it can help you.
